# Custom HTML5 video player controls with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, video, angularjs

I'm new with AngularJS. I must create customs controls for a video player (HTML5 `<video>`).
Basically, I would use `getElementById('myvideotag')`, listen clicks on the video for play/pause.
How I can do this with AngularJS ? Binding the click with `ng-click="videoPlayPause()"` but then, how I play or pause the video. How I use the classic methods of `<video>` ?

I guess it's really simple... I didn't get all the AngularJS concepts yet !

Thank you :)

Oh, the code... in the view:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" ng-click="video()">
    <source src="{{ current.url }}" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

In the right controller:

```
$scope.video = function() {
    this.pause(); // ???
}
```

Comment: The question is clear and I express myself wrong?

Comment: It looks like a decent question now. Before, without code or formatting it looked like a downvote. Somebody might be able to help, I'm not very experienced with Angular either.

Comment: Of course. Ok, thanks. In AngularJS, I dont really understand the philosophy about managing the DOM (yet... hard to forget jQuery habits !)

Comment: @Scofred Checkout the directives of Angularjs.

Comment: @sza ok, how can I use directives in this specific problem ? Have you a little example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

In your HTML, set `ng-click="video($event)"` **(don't forget the `$event` argument)**, which calls the following function:

```
$scope.video = function(e) {
    var videoElements = angular.element(e.srcElement);
    videoElements[0].pause();
}
```

I believe this is the simplest method.

[Documentation for angular.element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element)

Also, this might help you get used to Angular: [How do I “think in AngularJS/EmberJS(or other client MVC framework)” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-emberjsor-other-client-mvc-framework-if-i-have-a)

Comment: Thanks ! Now I understand how to manipulate the DOM. But, this code work only if in the ng-click method, I add "$event" in parameter and videoElement[0].pause();.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I edited my answer a little, does it look right now?

Comment: Shouldn't you use a directive to manipulate the DOM?

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 8):

For full control, like behaviour and look&feel, I'm using `videoJS` in angular.
I have a `ui-video` directive that wraps the `video` HTML5 element. This is necessary to overcome a problem of integration with AngularJS:

```
m.directive('uiVideo', function () {
    var vp; // video player object to overcome one of the angularjs issues in #1352 (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352). when the videojs player is removed from the dom, the player object is not destroyed and can't be reused.
    var videoId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 100); // in random we trust. you can use a hash of the video uri

    return {
        template: '<div class="video">' +
            '<video ng-src="{{ properties.src }}" id="video-' + videoId + '" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" >' +
                //'<source  type="video/mp4"> '+     /* seems not yet supported in angular */
                'Your browser does not support the video tag. ' +
            '</video></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.properties = 'whatever url';
            if (vp) vp.dispose();
            vp = videojs('video-' + videoId, {width: 640, height: 480 });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also take a look to my project Videogular.

https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular

It's a video player written in AngularJS, so you will have all the benefits of bindings and scope variables. Also you could write your own themes and plugins.

Answer (score 1):

**I also used [videojs](https://github.com/videojs/video.js)**

`bower install videojs --save`

I wanted to use my directive in a `ng-repeat` and with a scope object, so...  here's my version of it with props to Eduard above.  I didn't seem to have a problem with the video player disposal, but the [source tag issue referenced](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352) was an actual problem.

I also decided to write this up as an answer, so that I could give an example of how one might want to handle the videojs events.

**IMPORTANT!** Please note I am using Angular.js with Jinja2 templates, so I had to change my Angular HTML interpolation markers to `{[ ]}` from `{{ }}` in case anyone notices that as weird. I'll include that code too, so it's not weird for anyone.

**Interpolation tweak**

```
app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}');
}]);
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('uiVideo', function () {

  // Function for logging videojs events, possibly to server
  function playLog(player, videoId, action, logToDb) {
    action = action || 'view';
    var time = player.currentTime().toFixed(3);

    if (logToDb) {
      // Implement your own server logging here
    }

    // Paused
    if (player.paused()) {
      console.log('playLog: ', action + " at " + time + " " + videoId);

    // Playing
    } else {
      console.log('playLog: ', action + ", while playing at " + time + " " + videoId);
      if (action === 'play') {
        var wrapFn = function () {
          playLog(player, videoId, action, logToDb);
        };
        setTimeout(wrapFn, 1000);
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    template: [
      '<div class="video">',
        '<video id="video-{[ video.id ]}" class="video-js vjs-default-skin img-responsive" controls preload="none"',
          ' ng-src="{[ video.mp4 ]}"',
          ' poster="{[ video.jpg ]}"',
          ' width="240" height="120">',
        '</video>',
      '</div>'
    ].join(''),
    scope: {
      video: '=video',
      logToDb: '=logToDb'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.logToDb = scope.logToDb || false;

      var videoEl = element[0].children[0].children[0];
      var vp = videojs(videoEl, {},
        function(){
          this.on("firstplay", function(){
            playLog(vp, scope.video.id, 'firstplay', scope.logToDb);
          });
          this.on("play", function(){
            playLog(vp, scope.video.id, 'play', scope.logToDb);
          });
          this.on("pause", function(){
            playLog(vp, scope.video.id, 'pause', scope.logToDb);
          });
          this.on("seeking", function(){
            playLog(vp, scope.video.id, 'seeking', scope.logToDb);
          });
          this.on("seeked", function(){
            playLog(vp, scope.video.id, 'seeked', scope.logToDb);
          });
          this.on("ended", function(){
            playLog(vp, scope.video.id, 'ended', scope.logToDb);
          });
        }
      );

    }
  };
});
```

**Directive HTML usage**

```
  <div ng-repeat="row in videos">
        <ui-video video="row"></ui-video>
  </div>
```